# binary search tree in php

Tags: php, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been having some problems implementing the function __toString() to print the binary tree, I've searched on the Internet but I couldnt find anything. I would be grateful if anyone could help me!

Here's the code:

```
class Noeud {
    public $element;
    public $fd;
    public $fg;

    public function __construct($element){
        $this -> element = $element;
        $this-> fd = NULL;
        $this-> fg = NULL;
    }   
}


class Arbre {
    private $racine;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->racine = NULL;
    }
    public function isEmpty() {
        return $this->racine === null;
    }

    //public function remove($element); 

    public function add($element){
        $noeud = new Noeud($element);

        if($this->isEmpty()){
            $this->racine = $noeud;
        }
        else{
            $this->addNode($noeud,$this->racine);
        }
    }

    public function addNode($noeud, &$new){
        if($new === null){
            $new = $noeud;
        }
        else{
            if($node->element > $new->element){
                $this->addNode($node,$new->fd);
            }
            else if($node->element < $new->element){
                $this->addNode($node,$new->fg);
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
    } 

    public function __toString(){
          //
    }
```

Comment: search for BST traversing algorithms pseudo-code and convert it to PHP code, mainly there are two types: depth first search which explores a branch to it's end and then backtrack to other branches, and breadth first search which explores the tree level by level

Comment: @MikeBasha which traversal you want in order, post order, pre order .. ?

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what you do for the addNode() method in terms of traversing through the tree recursively and on each node you pass through just print the contents. So at each node you will print the contents and then print the contents of any child nodes. I'm not a PHP programmer but something like this:

```
printNode()
{
    // print contents of current node
     if left child exists
         left child->printNode()
     if right child exists
         right child->printNode()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an in-order traversal:

```
class Arbre {
    //
    // The existing code
    //

    public function __toString()
    {
        $this->printSubTree($this->racine, 0);
    }

    protected function printSubTree(Noeud $node, $depth)
    {
        if ($node === NULL) {
            return;
        }

        // Print the right subtree
        $this->printSubTree($node->fd, $depth + 1);
        // Print some spaces for alignment
        echo(str_pad('', $level, ' '));
        // Print the value in $node
        echo($node->element);
        // That's all for this line
        echo("\n");
        // Print the left subtree
        $this->printSubTree($node->fg, $depth + 1);
    }
}
```

It works nice on console scripts or, in HTML, if you put the output inside a `<PRE>` block. It prints the tree rotated with 90 degrees counter clockwise. Each node stays on its own line, the root starts on column `1` and each node that is at distance `N` from the root has its value printed starting from the column `N+1`. You can adjust the spacing by changing `+ 1` with a greater value in the calls to `printSubTree()`.